# How to unit test a conversion library?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm just starting out with unit testing in C#.
I have been reading about unit testing for a long time now, and I've already been playing around with NUnit, but this is the first time that I actually try to write real tests for real code.

But my problem is:
I'm having a hard time to come up with things that I can actually test.

The project I want to test is a conversion library (to convert lists of POCOs to ADO Recordsets).

So far, I've come up with only two things to test:

- if the recordset exists at all (not Null, not empty)
- if the content of each field is the same (--> if `RS!Foo == POCO.Foo`)

So, my questions are:

- What else can I test when my code just converts A to B?
- Or is this project too small / too simple / not a good example to write more than a few meaningful unit tests for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few things to test.  I would also suggest thinking about and potentially verifying:

- Private fields of `POCO` don't map through correctly
- Invalid entries in the list throw exceptions correctly
- Recordset length is correct
- Inheritance in POCO is handled as desired (ie: base class members map through as expected)

Answer (score 1):

Add a conversion test case where you know the exact input and output.  Then test that the code produces that answer exactly.

Comment: @JimMischel -- actually, no, one very good test case *is* a very good unit test.  But I think you meant that one test case doesn't make a very good test *suite*.  Agreed.  But this is just to suggest one way, out of many, that he could test the code.  And it will also double as a regression test, in case he makes future changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/) tool from Microsoft. It generates Unit tests after analyzing your code. Just a quick install of Visual studio plugin. Then Right click the class/method you want to test and in the context menu get Pex to generate all the possible code paths for you.